# Framework 4.6.2 not available in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, tls1.2, .net-4.6.1, .net-4.6.2

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 with framework version **4.6.1**. I need to use TLS 1.2 with my app. From what I've read, TLS 1.2 is the default with framework version **4.6.2**. But, that version isn't listed in visual studio:

[VS 2015 Frameworks listed in my project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TyUV.jpg)

I downloaded the 4.6.2 installer, but when I try to install it, the installer indicates:
 "*.NET Framework 4.6.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer.*"

So, my questions are:

1) Can framework 4.6.2 be used in VS 2015? (if so, what do I have to do?)
2) Can I use TLS 1.2 with the framework 4.6.1?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you trying to install the actual Framework or the [Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321)?

Comment: Thanks - apparently it was the "targeting pack" that I needed, not just the framework. I installed it, and 4.6.2 is now available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install the 4.6.2 SDK. It includes the reference assemblies for 4.6.2, which is what Visual Studio needs in order to target 4.6.2 for builds.

SDKs for all .NET versions (3.5+) are available from the [.NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks) page.